# Python pyqt4 Key Shortcuts

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am try to make a keyboard shortcut to exit the application after a Critical message pops up. i would like to make the user press the keyboard shortcut then be prompted with a Critical Message and after they click yes it will exit the program. ive been trying for a while now and couldnt get it to work. here is what i have

here is my code

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import random
import time
import os
import subprocess
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QIcon, QLabel, QPainter, QPixmap, QMessageBox, \
    QAction, QKeySequence


def CloseSC(self):
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
    msg.setText("This is a message box")
    msg.setInformativeText("This is additional information")
    msg.setWindowTitle("MessageBox demo")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 450)
        self.startUIWindow()

        self.actionExit = QAction(('E&xit'), self)
        self.actionExit.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"))
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(CloseSC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be add action to widget with `{your widget}.addAction({your action})`

This is my solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QAction, QKeySequence, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 450)
        self.actionExit = QAction(('E&xit'), self)
        self.actionExit.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"))
        self.addAction(self.actionExit)
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.CloseSC)

    def CloseSC(self):
        msg = QMessageBox(self)
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        msg.setText("This is a message box")
        msg.setInformativeText("This is additional information")
        msg.setWindowTitle("MessageBox demo")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        if msg.exec_() == QMessageBox.Ok:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

After Ctrl+Q

[image]